# Error message "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near '.'"

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to bulk update a certain table using the following query:

```
bcp master.dbo.Table_name in \C:\SQLDATA\abc.txt -S Computer_name\SQLEXPRESS -c -F3 -t"\t" -T.
```

I ran this exact same query yesterday and it worked, However this morning it doesn't. I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'

I don't see any fault in the SQL code I am using.

Please any suggestions?

Comment: You should include your SQL code, which appears to be generating this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the final poit in your bcp command  (after -T):

```
bcp master.dbo.Table_name in \C:\SQLDATA\abc.txt -S Computer_name\SQLEXPRESS -c -F3 -t"\t" -T
```